# Querying Geonames API to get only city country name

Tags: json, web-services, api, geolocation, geonames

Too much useless json data is being fetched when I request a specific country cities by hitting this URL:

```
http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=ksuhiyp&country=us&maxRows=1000
```

This returns too many json fields as you can see, question is hot to play with the query to get only city, country name ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with the additional parameter style=SHORT

http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?username=ksuhiyp&country=us&maxRows=1000&style=SHORT

The [docs](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) says: style, String SHORT,MEDIUM,LONG,FULL (optional), verbosity of returned xml document, default = MEDIUM

Comment: Awesome! , this reduced the returned data into the half thank you @YMomb

Comment: Your welcome. Please remember to accept answer that solves your problems ;-)